# Using jquery when select first option then hide other element

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I am trying to hide other html element, when I select 'fresher' option then current company, current ctc and notice elements are going to hide. I don't know how to this. please help me into this.

See below code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  Experience:
  <select name="experience" class="form-control" id="exp" value="<?php echo $experience; ?>"  required>
    <option></option>
    <option>fresher</option>
      <option>0-1 years</option>
      <option>1-3 years</option>
      <option>4-5 years</option>
      <option>5+ years</option>
    </select>
    <div class="error"><?php echo form_error("experience");?></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  current_company Name:
  <input type="text" name="ccn" class="form-control" id="ccmp" value="<?php echo set_value('ccn'); ?>" placeholder="current company name" required>
  <div class="error"><?php echo form_error("ccn");?></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
     Notice period:
  <select name="notice" class="form-control" id="notice" value="<?php echo $notice_period; ?>" placeholder="notice period in months" required>
    <option></option>
      <option>10-30 days</option>
      <option>1 month</option>
      <option>2 months</option>
      <option>3 months</option>
    </select>
    <div class="error"><?php echo form_error("notice");?></div>
    <br>
   current CTC:
    <input type="text" name="ctc" class="form-control" id="ctc" value="<?php echo set_value('ctc'); ?>" placeholder="currenty ctc" required>
  <div class="error"><?php echo form_error("ctc");?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I am trying this jquery

```
$(documnet).ready(function{
    $("#exp:selected").val('fresher').hide($("#ccmp"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `change event` for your `select` with `name=experience` and based on `selected text` `hide` or `show` the `closest` parent of the `ccmp` and `notice` elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="experience"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).find("option:selected").text()=="fresher") //check if option selected is fresher
      $('#ccmp, select[name="notice"]').closest('.form-group').hide();//hide the parents
    else
      $('#ccmp, select[name="notice"]').closest('.form-group').show();//show the parents
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Experience:
    <select name="experience" class="form-control" id="exp" value="<?php echo $experience; ?>" required>
      <option></option>
      <option>fresher</option>
      <option>0-1 years</option>
      <option>1-3 years</option>
      <option>4-5 years</option>
      <option>5+ years</option>
    </select>
    <div class="error">
      <?php echo form_error( "experience");?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    current_company Name:
    <input type="text" name="ccn" class="form-control" id="ccmp" value="<?php echo set_value('ccn'); ?>" placeholder="current company name" required>
    <div class="error">
      <?php echo form_error( "ccn");?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Notice period:
    <select name="notice" class="form-control" id="notice" value="<?php echo $notice_period; ?>" placeholder="notice period in months" required>
      <option></option>
      <option>10-30 days</option>
      <option>1 month</option>
      <option>2 months</option>
      <option>3 months</option>
    </select>
    <div class="error">
      <?php echo form_error( "notice");?>
    </div>
    <br>current CTC:
    <input type="text" name="ctc" class="form-control" id="ctc" value="<?php echo set_value('ctc'); ?>" placeholder="currenty ctc" required>
    <div class="error">
      <?php echo form_error( "ctc");?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx man, you are a champ. please tell me if there any site where i am practice jquery . if you know any?

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer if it worked for you :) to potentially help others in the future!

Comment: @DineshGawande.. Just go with youtube video tutorials uploaded by KudVenkat.. He is a real champ.. :) Also do not forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the selected option is "fresher" then it will hide the `#ccmp` element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#exp").on('change', function() {
        if ($("#exp option:selected").text() === "fresher") {
            $("#ccmp").hide();  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made an error at the level of your script. Instead of "**$(document).ready**", you typed "***$(documnet).ready***". Try changing it and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `change` event to your select drop down and then check its `val`.   Hide works on an element as in

```
$(id).hide()
```

not `.hide(el)`, so you need to swap that around as well

```
$(function() {
   $("#exp").change(function() {
       if ($("#exp").val() == "fresher") {
           $("#cmp").hide();
       }
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class="hideClass" to all the elements you want to hide, and try this code.

```
    $(document).on('change','#exp',function(e){
         var text = $('#exp').find(":selected").text();
         if(text=='fresher'){
            $('.hideClass').hide();
         }
    });
```